# Do containers use the same OS disk cache?

Tags: containers, diskcache, oscache

When running multiple containers on single server, does each container have its own OS disk cache? Or is the OS disk cache shared between all containers?

Is the answer different when there are multiple physical disks, and any one disk is only used by one container?

Is there a difference between Linux and Windows?

I have two services that do a lot of disk reads, but each has its own data set. I want to optimized cache hits. If I deploy them as docker containers on the same machine, will they constantly flush each other's data?